# Minimum from Multiple Columns Syntax

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is what I have currently:

```
UPDATE dbo.claims
SET EXP_FEE = CASE WHEN CASE WHEN a.DLV_SYS <> 'MAIL' and a.FEE < a.CASH and a.FEE < a.GROSS_AMT THEN a.FEE
         WHEN a.USUAL_AND_CUSTOMARY < a.FEE and a.CASH < a.GROSS_AMT THEN a.CASH 
         ELSE a.GROSS_AMT
```

I am running into an issue because I need to put in another condition and I'm getting an error.

```
UPDATE dbo.claims
SET EXP_COPAY = CASE WHEN a.DLV_SYS <> 'MAIL' and a.FEE < a.CASH and a.FEE < a.GROSS_AMT THEN a.COPAY
         WHEN a.CASH < a.FEE and a.CASH < a.GROSS_AMT THEN a.CASH 
         ELSE a.GROSS_AMT and WHEN a.DLV_SYS = 'MAIL' and a.FEE < a.GROSS_AMT THEN a.FEE
         ELSE a.GROSS_AMT end
```

When the DLV_SYS is 'MAIL', I need to compare the lower of two amounts, and when the DLV_SYS is not 'MAIL', I need to compare the lower of three amounts.  Can I do this in one statement?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your intent correctly, you probably want to nest the `CASE` expressions, like

```
UPDATE dbo.claims
SET EXP_COPAY = 
CASE 
   WHEN a.DLV_SYS <> 'MAIL' and a.FEE < a.CASH and a.FEE < a.GROSS_AMT 
     THEN a.COPAY
   WHEN a.CASH < a.FEE and a.CASH < a.GROSS_AMT 
     THEN a.CASH 
   WHEN a.DLV_SYS = 'MAIL' 
     CASE WHEN a.FEE < a.GROSS_AMT 
       THEN a.FEE
       ELSE a.GROSS_AMT 
     END
   ELSE a.GROSS_AMT
END
```

or simply

```
UPDATE dbo.claims
SET EXP_COPAY = 
CASE 
   WHEN a.DLV_SYS <> 'MAIL' and a.FEE < a.CASH and a.FEE < a.GROSS_AMT 
     THEN a.COPAY
   WHEN a.CASH < a.FEE and a.CASH < a.GROSS_AMT 
     THEN a.CASH 
   WHEN a.DLV_SYS = 'MAIL' AND a.FEE < a.GROSS_AMT 
     THEN a.FEE
   ELSE a.GROSS_AMT
END
```